# Error con decimales???? Python

Tags: python

trato de calcular el salario base con horas y bonificaciones pero al momento de realizar los calculos me doy de cuenta que faltan decimales en el resultado final, ya intente cambiando algunas ( `/ a % y //`) sin notar mucha diferencia.

```python
    #Datos de entrada
    salario_base, horas_trabajadas, bonificaciones = input().split()
    
    
    #Proceso
    salario_base = int(salario_base)
    horas_trabajadas = int(horas_trabajadas)
    bonificaciones = int(bonificaciones)
    
    valor_hora = salario_base / 199
    
    valor_horas_extra = valor_hora * 45 / 100
    
    
    if bonificaciones == 1:
        bonus = salario_base * 5.5 / 100
        salario_total = salario_base + valor_horas_extra + bonus
    else:
        salario_total = salario_base + valor_horas_extra
    
    
    
    descuento = salario_total * 13 
    descuento = descuento/100
    
    salario_con_descuento = salario_total - descuento
    
    salario_con_descuento = round(salario_con_descuento,1)
    salario_total =round(salario_total,1)
    
    print(f'{salario_total} {salario_con_descuento}')
```

los datos de entrada son: `2355255 2 1`
y debería de salir: `2519116.8 2191631.6`
pero me da: `2490120.0 2166404.4`

Comment: podrías explicar que es lo que hace tu código?, por que hacer `/` es diferente a `//` y tambien a `%`, tal vez usas los operadores mal

Answer (score 2):

Cambiando los int por float, ya que int te transforma un numero con decimales en entero. Con float entrarian los enteros pero tambien los decimales

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), recuerda que tu respuesta no debe ser otra pregunta. Si sabes que el problema es el tipo de dato entonces respáldalo con argumentos sólidos y explica cómo eso lo ayudaría a solucionar su problema

Answer (score 2):

En principio el problema creo qe viene de no sumar el importe de las horas extras, a las que denominas horas trabajadas.
para facilitar la comprension de la entrada de datos lo paso a una función.

```
# Datos de entrada
#  salario_base, horas_trabajadas, bonificaciones = input().split()
def proceso(salario_base, horas_extras_trabajadas, bonificaciones):
    # Proceso
    salario_base = float(salario_base)
    horas_extras_trabajadas = int(horas_extras_trabajadas)
    bonificaciones = int(bonificaciones)
    bonus = 0

    valor_hora = salario_base / 199  #  Supongo que el mes tiene 199 horas

    valor_horas_extra = valor_hora * (100 + 45) / 100  #  Supongo que las horas extras se pagan 45% más

    importe_horas_extras = valor_horas_extra * horas_extras_trabajadas
    if bonificaciones == 1:
        bonus = salario_base * 5.5 / 100  #  Bonus del 5.5% del salario

    salario_total = salario_base + bonus + importe_horas_extras

    descuento = salario_total * 13 / 100  #  Descuento del 13%

    salario_con_descuento = salario_total - descuento

    #  Dejar datos con solo 1 decimal
    salario_con_descuento = round(salario_con_descuento, 1)
    salario_total = round(salario_total, 1)

    #  Imprime
    print(f'{salario_total} {salario_con_descuento}')


proceso(2355255, 2, 1)
```

Creo que con los comentarios del código se ve bastante bien.
Espero haber podido colaborar.